# Set SingleSelection in QListView

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

I am writing an application in PySide2 and I have developed a class inheriting from Qdialog to display a list with checkboxes:

The code of the class:

```
class ListDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, items, all_checked = False, parent=None):
        super(ListDialog, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        form = QFormLayout(self)

        self.listView = QListView(self)
        self.listView.setSelectionMode(QTableView.NoSelection)

        form.addRow(self.listView)
        self.model = QStandardItemModel(self.listView)
        for item in items:
            # create an item with a caption
            standardItem = QStandardItem(item)
            standardItem.setCheckable(True)
            standardItem.setEditable(False)
            if all_checked:
                standardItem.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)
            self.model.appendRow(standardItem)
        self.listView.setModel(self.model)
```

The result (plus some extra code):

[image: list image example]

As it is, you can *check* multiple checkboxes, but I need to make it a **single selection**.

Note the line:

```
self.listView.setSelectionMode(QTableView.NoSelection)
```

At first, I thought `setSelectionMode` was responsible for this behaviour but this controls only the highlighting on the items of the list and not its checkboxes. Therefore I set it to `NoSelection` for not highlighting the text part, the checkboxes are working!

Is there an easy way to set the selection mode to single? Or should I overload the signal that controls the box checking to unselect all the boxes and then select the one I clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do that it to use a proxy model which will handle the single selection and the signal `QStandardItemModel::itemChanged` to know when user clicks on an item.

For example:

```
class SingleCheckProxyModel(QIdentityProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, model, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        model.itemChanged.connect(self.checkSingleCheck)
        self.setSourceModel(model)
        self.currentItemChecked = None

    def checkSingleCheck(self, item):
        if self.currentItemChecked:
            self.currentItemChecked.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
        if item.checkState(): # Allows the user to uncheck then check the same item
            self.currentItemChecked = item
        else:
            self.currentItemChecked = None


class ListDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, items, all_checked = False, parent=None):
        super(ListDialog, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("kjnve")
        form = QFormLayout(self)

        self.listView = QListView(self)
        self.listView.setSelectionMode(QTableView.NoSelection)

        form.addRow(self.listView)
        self.model = QStandardItemModel(self.listView)
        for item in items:
            # create an item with a caption
            standardItem = QStandardItem(item)
            standardItem.setCheckable(True)
            standardItem.setEditable(False)
            if all_checked:
                standardItem.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)
            self.model.appendRow(standardItem)
        self.listView.setModel(SingleCheckProxyModel(self.model)) # Use proxy
```

The `checkSingleCheck` method will be called when the user clicks on an item. But, if you want to be able to edit the items, you have to adapt this function.

Comment: `QIdentityProxyModel` is part of QtCore. Actually, you don't need to use a proxy model and can put the method directly in your `ListDialog` class. I prefer use a proxy to split the business logic between the view and the model.

Comment: Ok anyway, it's working. The only thing I add to change was `self.currentItemChecked.setCheckState(False)` with `self.currentItemChecked.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)`

Comment: Can you provide the method without the proxy?